# What happen if I stop publishing my app from a country on Google Play?

Tags: google-play, admob, google-play-console

I made an Android app which has Admob ads and I stopped publishing my app from a spesific country. But there are 17 people which have already downloaded my app from this country.

Now, what happens to them after the stop publishing my app from their country? 
Can I still make money from their ads click? 
Is my app going to remove from their devices automatically?

Answer (score 1):

They still will see your ads (and click).
Admob and Google Play are different services.

The apps will still contain your app. Google Play is just a shop.

Comment: How can I block ads from them?

Comment: Admob.com you can setup ads here